# How to select the text on the button?

Tags: button

For example, I have a `Button`

```
Button["http://www.wolfram.com", 
  NotebookLocate[{URL["http://www.wolfram.com"], None}], 
  Appearance -> None]
```

How to select text with the mouse?

Comment: I would tend to say "you can't do that with the mouse".

Comment: It is not clear, what does the author want.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I think the OP wants to be able to select the button's text with the mouse.

Comment: I think that the only way is to press Ctrl+Shift+E and then select relevant piece of the code.

Comment: @Öskå The question is, what is the ultimate aim of it. That is, what will the OP do afterwards. I can easily copy/paste the whole button (which is this case has the appearance of the text), including pasting it into Mma with and into a Word document without the button functionality.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch But you can't select for example "www." from the button, can you?

Comment: @Öskå Of course not. Then you select/copy the whole button, open a notepad, paste the button there and select www this time from the notepad. Or even better: you just type "www" in whatever place you like. Done. The question is, therefore, what is the ultimate aim of such a selection. But that I have already written.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EventHandler` with a modifier key to switch between `Button` and text-copiable styles:

```
With[{
      buttonFunc = Button[#, NotebookLocate[{URL[#], None}]] &,
      stringFunc = InputField[#, String, FrameMargins -> 20] &
     },
     DynamicModule[{f = buttonFunc},
                   EventHandler[
                                Dynamic[f["http://www.wolfram.com"]],
                                {
                                 "MouseEntered" :>
                                     If[CurrentValue["ShiftKey"],
                                        f = stringFunc,
                                        f = buttonFunc ]
                                }]]
    ]
```

[image: switch styles with modifier key]

The result will be an ordinary `Button` for normal mouse actions, but will turn into an editable `InputField` when mouseover the button with <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed.

Comment: Thank you! I think it is best solution.

Comment: @Kypaku Glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score 2):

From your example in seems you are trying to create a hyperlink.  You can do that with [`Hyperlink`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hyperlink.html):

```
Hyperlink["click me", "http://www.wolfram.com", ButtonNote -> "http://www.wolfram.com"]
```

> ```
> click me
> ```

If you right-click on the output `click me` you should get a menu with two items:

- Copy Hyperlink
- Copy Address

The first command will copy the button text ("click me") while the second will copy the URL itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addendum to Mr.Wizard'a answer.

First, I ask Mr.Wizard: were y0u not put off even a little by the code editor's bright red coloring of `ButtonNote`? According to the docs, that option has been superseded by `StatusArea` since V6. Your code still works, of couse, but to bring it up date, it can be rewritten as

```
Hyperlink[
  StatusArea["click me", "http://www.wolfram.com"], 
  "http://www.wolfram.com"]
```

Second, the context menu, which appears upon right-clicking the mouse, only seems to work properly if the link's target is a URL. When the target is a tagged cell in the current notebook, the second choice `Copy Address` acts the same as the first choice, `Copy Hyperlink`. This looks like a bug to me. This behavior can be confirmed by creating a cell with the tag "target" and evaluating

```
Hyperlink[
  StatusArea["click me", "target"], 
  {EvaluationNotebook[], "target"}]
```

Finally, the OP asked for a button. That is easily provided.

```
Hyperlink[
  StatusArea["click me", "Open http://www.wolfram.com in the default browser"], 
 "http://www.wolfram.com", 
  Appearance -> "DialogBox"]
```

[image: button]

Comment: Me, put off by a syntax warning?  Surely you jest.  If `ButtonNote` is deprecated someone forgot to tell the developers since it's used internally quite a bit.  In fact it's what `ToExpression` thinks is the correct syntax for *your* example: `Hyperlink[StatusArea["click me", "http://www.wolfram.com"], "http://www.wolfram.com"] // ToBoxes // (ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Hold] &) // InputForm`  :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I'm aware of `ButtonNote`'s use internally. I'm sure that's why your version of the code not only works now, but will continue to work. A portion of my intent in posting this addendum was to convey my feeling that `Hyperlink` is a just little screwed up.

Comment: FYI: You already have my vote.  I'm just having fun with this, as I think you know. :-)